How to bundle service worker with imports in laravel vite
I am trying to setup service workers on my laravel vite app. I want the service worker to work with the Google workbox library. However, when importing the workbox dependencies in sw.js, the following message appears in the browser console:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at sw.js:1:1)
I already tried the vite-plugin-pwa but I prefer Google workbox atm. I feel like Google workbox enables more control over the service worker.
Also, I tried creating a custom file in vite.config.js, named sw.js, the benefit being that the 'import' is bundled into sw.js. But this generates a build/assets/sw-[HASH].js file. My guess is that the file should always be named the same (in my case sw.js) and controlling newer versions of the service worker should be done within the service worker itself. Please assist me if I'm wrong.
In my app.js, we can see that in dev mode, I'm using ES Module, with { type: 'module', }. This results in an error in the chrome console: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/js/sw.js', <----------
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
})


app.js:
// Register the service worker
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // Wait for the 'load' event to not block other work
    window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
        // Try to register the service worker.
        try {
            // Capture the registration for later use, if needed
            let reg

            // Use ES Module version of our Service Worker in development
            if (import.meta.env?.DEV) {
                reg = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', {
                    type: 'module',
                })
            } else {
                // In production, use the normal service worker registration
                reg = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
            }

            console.log('Service worker registered! ', reg)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(' Service worker registration failed: ', err)
        }
    })
}

sw.js:
import { warmStrategyCache, offlineFallback } from '/workbox-recipes'
import { CacheFirst, StaleWhileRevalidate } from '/workbox-strategies'
import { registerRoute } from '/workbox-routing'
import { CacheableResponsePlugin } from '/workbox-cacheable-response'
import { ExpirationPlugin } from '/workbox-expiration'

// Set up page cache
const pageCache = new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'page-cache',
    plugins: [
        new CacheableResponsePlugin({
            statuses: [0, 200],
        }),
        new ExpirationPlugin({
            maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
        }),
    ],
})

warmStrategyCache({
    urls: ['/index.html', '/'],
    strategy: pageCache,
})

registerRoute(({ request }) => request.mode === 'navigate', pageCache)

// Set up asset cache
registerRoute(
    ({ request }) => ['style', 'script', 'worker'].includes(request.destination),
    new StaleWhileRevalidate({
        cacheName: 'asset-cache',
        plugins: [
            new CacheableResponsePlugin({
                statuses: [0, 200],
            }),
        ],
    }),
)

// Set up offline fallback
offlineFallback({
    pageFallback: '/offline.html',
})

